# how to use jquery variables in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am using jquery and what I want to do here is to be able to set the image that will show up based upon the link that is being hovered to.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
  $('img').hide();
  $('a').mouseenter(function(){
    var currentimg= $(this).html();
    alert(currentimg);
    $("img[src=currentimg.jpg]").show(); //I want to use currentimg variable here for the name of the jpg file
  });

  $('a').mouseleave(function(){
    $('img').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just concatenate the string for use, for example:

```
$("img[src='" + currentimg +"']").show();
```

Just to note, there's also a [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) shortcut for `.mouseenter(handler).mouseleave(handler)`, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('img').hide();
  $('a').hover(function(){
     var currentimg = $(this).html();
     $("img[src='" + currentimg +"']").show();
  }, function(){
     $('img').hide();
  });
});
```